# Detect if one point is inside polygons using GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, point-in-polygon

First I import a shapefile

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile_path = "data/TRI_75_SIG_DI/TRI_PARI_SIG_DI/n_tri_pari_carte_inond_s_075.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
```

And it works fine.

[image]

Then I can display the polygons :

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[48.8566, 2.3522], zoom_start=12)
folium.GeoJson(gdf).add_to(m)
m
```

And it also works

[image]

Now, I choose a point, and we can see that it is in the polygons:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

point_coordinates = (2.3546, 48.8517) 
point = Point(point_coordinates)
m = folium.Map(location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]], zoom_start=13)
folium.Marker(
    location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]],
    icon=folium.Icon(color='blue'),
    popup="Point d'intérêt"
).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

And I used the following code, that does not work:

```
gdf.geometry.contains(point)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get back a series of True/False values calculated for each polygon row that does the geometry comparison. True values would represent polygons that contain the geometry. This writes boolean values to new "contains_point" column in GeoDataFrame.

```
   gdf['contains_point'] = gdf.geometry.contains(point)
```

More information is included in the link below:

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.contains

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to query a dataset with spatial data is to use a spatial index. This is a lot faster and more efficient than calculating an intersection/contains for all elements in the dataset.

For a GeoDataFrame you can do this using [geopandas.sindex.query](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query.html):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

polys = [
    shapely.box(xmin=xmin, ymin=ymin, xmax=xmin + 10, ymax=ymin + 10)
    for xmin in range(0, 100, 10)
    for ymin in range(0, 100, 10)
]
grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=polys)

# Search for polygons that intersect with the point
print(grid.iloc[grid.sindex.query(shapely.Point(55, 55), predicate="intersects")])
```